# $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ cubic function, goes through these points $(0,1) ,(-1,-2), (1,2), (2,9)$

Tags: cubics

How can I solve it without using matrix? I tried it to solve by using systems. But I have no idea how deal with "$0$"

Comment: It simply says that $d=1$.

Comment: You could use Lagrange interpolation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) though ad hoc methods tend to be quicker for small examples in practice. Here the value for $0$ is immediately helpful and the values for $\pm 1$ will isolate $a+c$ and $b+d$ for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}d=1\\-a+b-c+d=-2\\a+b+c+d=2\\8a+4b+2c+d=9.\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 1):

Given equation, $$y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$$ ,On putting the points $(0,1),(-1,-2),(1,2),(2,9)$ following system of equation are obtained $$\begin{align} d &=1\\ -a+b-c+d &=-2\\a+b+c+d &=2\\8a+4b+2c+d &=9.\end{align}.$$

On adding $(2)$ and $(3)$ and using $(1)$, $ 2b + 2 = 0 \Rightarrow b = -1$

On multiplying $(3)$ by $8$ ,subtracting it from $(4)$, and using value of $b$, gives $c = 2/3$ , and finally placing all this value in $(2)$ gives $a = 4/3$

Hence, values are  $ a = 4/3, b = -1 , c = 2/3$ and $d = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Since we have the values of the polynomial at successive integers (-1,0,1 and 2), one way to find the interpolating polynomial is to use a table of finite differences:
$$\begin{matrix}
-2\\
    &3\\
1   &   &-2\\
    &1  &    &8\\
2   &   &6\\
    &7\\
9
\end{matrix}$$
Each column in the table is derived from the the previous column by applying the forward difference operator $\Delta(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$.  We can then plug the differences on the upper diagonal into [Newton's Forward Difference Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsForwardDifferenceFormula.htmlhttp://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsForwardDifferenceFormula.html):
$$f(s) = -2 + (3) s + (-2)(1/2!) s(s-1) + 8 (1/3!)s(s-1)(s-2)$$
But the Newton formula assumes the series of $s$ values starts at $0$, whereas our data starts at $-1$, so we need to make the substitution $s=x+1$ in order to fit the data given:
$$f(x) = -2 + (3) (x+1) + (-2)(1/2!)(x+1)x + 8(1/3!) (x+1)x(x-1)$$

Expanding this polynomial will yield the coefficients $a,b,c$ and $d$.

Comment: Nice answer (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute every point in the equation and solve a system in 4 unknown (a,b,c,d) with four equation, one for every point. 
The system is
$$d=1$$
$$-a+b-c+d=-2$$
$$a+b+c+d=2$$
$$8a+4b+2c+d=9$$

so the point with $0$ tells you that $d=1$. From this point you can use every method you want to solve it.
(Putting it on a linear system solver I find that $a=\frac{4}{3}$, $b=-1$, $c=\frac{2}{3}$ and $d=1$).

Comment: yeah my bad. I edited the typo. Sorry.